# Error in the service when using forwardRef

Tags: nestjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vkIe.png)

I have been having a dependency problem that is solved by injecting the service and using forwardRef, but this generates a strange error and the service responds only once and then the dependencies are lost, example: when calling the service the first time it returns the response, when trying to consume it again I get this error "Cannot read property 'axiosRef' of undefined" as if the HttpService was no longer available.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY5yR.png)

auth0.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule, forwardRef(() => UsersModule)],
  controllers: [Auth0Controller],
  providers: [Auth0Service, ConfigService],
})
export class Auth0Module {}
```

auth0.service.ts

```
export class Auth0Service {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => UsersService))
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private httpService: HttpService,
    private configService: ConfigService,
  ) {}
```

users.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule,
    HttpModule,
    forwardRef(() => SquareModule),
    TenantModule,
  ],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService, ...usersProviders],
  exports: [...usersProviders, UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

users.service.ts

```
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    private squareService: SquareService,
    @Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request,
    @Inject('USER_MODEL') private usersModel: Model<any>,
  ) {}
```

square.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    forwardRef(() => UsersModule),
    forwardRef(() => TenantModule),
  ],
  controllers: [SquareController],
  providers: [
    SquareService,
    ConfigService,
    SDKSquareService,
    CryptoService,
    Auth0Service,
    TokenService,
  ],
  exports: [
    SquareService,
    ConfigService,
    SDKSquareService,
    CryptoService,
    Auth0Service,
  ],
})
export class SquareModule {}
```

square.service.ts

```
export class SquareService {

  constructor(
    private configService: ConfigService,
    private sdkSquareService: SDKSquareService,
    private tenantService: TenantService,
    private auth0Service: Auth0Service,
    private tokenService: TokenService,
    private httpService: HttpService,
    @Inject('USER_MODEL') private userModel: Model<any>,
    @Inject('TENANT_MODEL') private tenantModel: Model<any>,
  ) {}
```

Comment: So this works once and then doesn't? That doesn't make much sense in the context of Nest, unless somehow you're overwriting the `httpService` property

Comment: @JayMcDoniel if it is something strange it is as if the dependency of the HttpService is no longer available but it only happens if I use the forwardRef

Comment: the problem comes since I am trying to use UsersService there in that service, and it doesn't work unless I put the forwardRef

Comment: What context are you using this service in? Is `UsersService` possibly request scoped and you're making a call to the `HttpService` when there's no active request? There needs to be more information here, or a way for someone to reproduce the error

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I have just added more information